# C++ Unhandled exception when reading file and writing to variables-- getline error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, unhandled-exception

Here I am just trying to write the input file data into my class variables. The class variables are public and act as common variables. There're similar topics on the Internet but after hours spent, I still cannot fix the error. If I instead write while ( (myfile >> map.at(i).x_p >> map.at(i).f ) ), there will be OK, but that's not desirable. My file Book1.csv is listed as follows:

```
9, 2.25 
7, 3
5, 3
3, 3
1, 2.25
```

For each object, I would like to write 2 variables, and I write my code on Visual Studio 2013 Express.
I am grateful for any hint and suggestion.

Here is my code.

```
 class node {           
  public:
  string x_p;       
  string f;     // force
  };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
vector<node> map(5);

ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("Book1.csv");

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( (getline(myfile, map.at(i).x_p, ',') ) )    // close the loop when the file reading reaches its end
    {
        cout << "KK" << endl;       
//      getline(myfile, map.at(i).x_p, ',');
        getline(myfile, map.at(i).f);
        cout << map.at(i).x_p << ", " << map.at(i).f << endl;
        ++i;


    }
    myfile.close();

}
else cout << "Unable to open file";

cout << "end" << endl;  //test

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What is your exact error?

Comment: Please provide MCVE. Your current code will not even compile. For example, `i` variable is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The code successfully reads five lines. Then it *attempts* to read a sixth. That sixth `getline` that would have bounced off the end of the file, failed and exited the loop if `at(i)` hadn't thrown an exception trying to reach into the sixth element of a five element `vector` for a `string` to put the possible sixth line into.

Possible solution:

```
while (i < map.size() && 
       getline(myfile, map.at(i).x_p, ',') && 
       getline(myfile, map.at(i).f)) )
```

Also gets rid of the brittleness of misbehaviour over a line that ends too soon.

Comment: </code>
while (i<5) // ch is used to write the comma in between the figures
  {
   myfile >> map.at(i).x_p >> ch >> map.at(i).f; 
                    ............
               }
</code>
I tried this and it worked as well. I think your way would succeed.
Thanks for editing for me.
I don't know how to add code tags.

Comment: @kd37 tag wasn't me. i just made the linefeeds in your input file visible.